# In-line block definition - how to?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, io, block, grand-central-dispatch

Right now I am dispatching a block of code inside a method to go download stuff for me using following format:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloader("downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async (downloader, ^{

//do stuff

});
```

what I am trying to do now is have that block return a UIImage for me, which I can then use as the return for the method:

```
-(UIImage *) myMethod:

dispatch_queue_t downloader("downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async (downloader, ^{

//do stuff to get UIImage

     dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{

     return UIImage;  //this is the image that image I want myMethod to return

     });    
});
```

how ever I am getting passing parameter to incompatible type errors. I realize that is because I am not declaring that the block has a return value.

How can I declare that the block returns a UIImage right inside dispatch_async? Is this even possible or is would the method already be done by the time the block finishes execution?

Comment: This is what happens: `would the method already be done by the time the block finishes execution`

Comment: Take in mid that asynchronous methods can never return anything. Since the code you are executing in the thread does not run in the main thread, but the all other code runs in the main thread and goes serially from top to bottom, you will not be able to return any thing from the asynchronous call like such. Either use dispatch_sync to return or create your own block and pass as a parameter to execute after certain task finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the return would require your method to be synchronous, so there's no solution that way. You will need to use a block as part of the function, like this:

```
- (void)myMethodOnFinish:(void(^)(UIImage *))finishBlock {

    dispatch_queue_t downloader("downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async (downloader, ^{

        //do stuff to get UIImage
        UIImage *result = ...;

         dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
         //this is the image that image I want myMethod to return
             finishBlock(result);
        });    
    });
}
```

and call like this:

```
[self myMethodOnFinish:^(UIImage *image) {

    self.imageView.image = image; // or whatever you need to do            

}];
```